# Is "real time protection" on Windows affected by the configured Exclusion list?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-defender

I want to disable "real time protection" for certain folders on Windows 10.

Will adding to the Windows Defender Exclusion settings do that?

> Settings > Update & Security > Windows Defender > Open Windows Defender Security Central > Protection Against Viruses & Threats > Advanced Config… > Exclusions

Or must I also edit a group policy to disable "real time protection"  altogether?

This post -- [Speedup WSL by disabling Windows Real-time protection](https://leandrw.com.br/speedup-wsl-by-disabling-windows-real-time-protection/) -- implies that the Exclusion list is not sufficient. It says,

> Adding WSL to exclusion list may speedup things a little bit, but not so. There is one more thing bringing your performance down: Window Defender real-time protection.
>
> As noticed by David Tansey in [this WSL issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1932), real-time protection have a HUGE impact in developer tools like Visual Studio build tool and tools like Kubernetes and etc., including WSL.
>
> We will disable it, but be aware: you will may be more vulnerable for some common attacks through malicious script execution.
>
> So, let’s disable:
>
> **Using Group Policy (gpedit.exe) to disable real-time protection:** (etc.)

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking specifically with relation to WSL, and issues within WSL environment due to Windows Defender?  The exclusion list should need be enough to disable active protection, it certainly does get disabled on files in an exlcusion folder in my experience, but I am not trying to exclude folders that only exist within WSL.

Comment: I guess it's two questions: 1) In theory and in general, does the Exclusion affect real-time protection 2) In the specific case of WSL is it true that using the Exclusion is insufficient and that the real-time protection feature should be switched off entirely?

Comment: The article you provided in your question is accurate.

Comment: @Ramhound Does that comment tell me something I didn't know when I posted this question? Perhaps an answer could include a reference (e.g. to documentation) or a description of your personal experience. If you're saying that Exclusion didn't work whereas disabling the feature did work, why do you say that? Did you try to exclude something in particular, unsuccessfully?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exclusions apply to real-time protection.

> You can define exclusions for Microsoft Defender Antivirus that apply
> to scheduled scans, on-demand scans, and always-on, real-time
> protection and monitoring.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/configure-extension-file-exclusions-microsoft-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide

I think what the blog post is getting at is the overall performance of WSL is affected by Defender's real-time protection, despite excluding the WSL package folder. That doesn't mean that Defender real-time protection isn't honouring the exclusion; just that there's a limit to the performance improvement that this will bring.